# Use python in hive transform occured Error 20003

Tags: hadoop, hive

I already execute

```
add file hdfs://namenodeip:8020/pythonpath/udf.py
```

But occured following exception

```
2016-03-30 05:06:21,946 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1458297182532_21468_m_000005_0: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:199)
    ... 8 more
```

How to solve the problem?Thanks.